# ScalaCheck specificy minimum successful tests for property

Tags: scala, scalacheck

I'm trying to make sure that my ScalaCheck property runs 500 times instead of the default 100 times. I'm having trouble configuring this though.

```
class BlockSpec extends Properties("BlockSpec") with BitcoinSLogger {

  val myParams = Parameters.default.withMinSuccessfulTests(500)
  override def overrideParameters(p: Test.Parameters) = myParams

  property("Serialization symmetry") =
  Prop.forAll(BlockchainElementsGenerator.block) { block =>
    logger.warn("Hex:" + block.hex)
    Block(block.hex) == block
  }
}
```

However when I actually run this test it only says 100 tests passed successfully

EDIT:

```
$ sbt
[info] Loading project definition from /home/chris/dev/bitcoins-core/project
[info] Set current project to bitcoin-s-core (in build file:/home/chris/dev/bitcoins-core/)
> test-only *BlockSpec*
[info] + BlockSpec.Serialization symmetry: OK, passed 100 tests.
[info] Elapsed time: 1 min 59.775 sec 
[info] ScalaCheck
[info] Passed: Total 1, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 1
[info] ScalaTest
[info] Run completed in 2 minutes.
[info] Total number of tests run: 0
[info] Suites: completed 0, aborted 0
[info] Tests: succeeded 0, failed 0, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
[info] No tests were executed.
[info] Passed: Total 1, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 1
[success] Total time: 123 s, completed Aug 1, 2016 11:36:17 AM
>
```

How do I actually pass this to my property?

Comment: i guess you call that from sbt? can you show us how you call this property? and maybe try with `property.check` from a REPL?

Comment: I do use sbt, i'll add the command to the OP

Comment: Looks like when I run it from the console I get only 100 tests passed as well `scala> res1._2.check
+ OK, passed 100 tests.`

Comment: what about `res1._2.check(_.withMinSuccessfulTests(500))`?

Comment: That does work, but it doesn't really answer the original question -- there should be some way to pass these parameters to the class and run them with sbt

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand you can specify the test parameters at two levels and they don't seem to communicate.

The first option is within the property as you're trying to do:

```
import org.scalacheck.Properties
import org.scalacheck.Test.{ TestCallback, Parameters }
import org.scalacheck.Prop.{ forAll, BooleanOperators }
import org.scalacheck.Test

class TestFoo extends Properties("BlockSpec") {

  override def overrideParameters(p: Parameters) = 
    p.withMinSuccessfulTests(1000000)

  property("Serialization symmetry") = forAll { n: Int =>
    (n > 0) ==> (math.abs(n) == n)
  }

}
```

This will have no impact as long as you don't call `.check` on the property.
Can be from the sbt shell or directly within the class.

Now if you want to impact the number of tests run when calling the `sbt:test` target, it seems you have to play with options `build.sbt` (taken from [here](https://github.com/rickynils/scalacheck/blob/master/examples/simple-sbt/build.sbt)):

```
name := "scalacheck-demo"

scalaVersion := "2.11.5"

libraryDependencies += "org.scalacheck" %% "scalacheck" % "1.12.2" % "test"

testOptions in Test += Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.ScalaCheck, "-maxSize", "5", "-minSuccessfulTests", "33", "-workers", "1", "-verbosity", "1")
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to allow per-test or per-property settings?

Answer (score 1):

There's definitely an easier way to achieve that than overriding any kind of global test config:

```
class SampleTest extends FlatSpec
  with Matchers with GeneratorDrivenPropertyChecks {

  it should "work for a basic scenario" in {
    // This will require 500 successful tests to succeed
    forAll(minSuccessful(500)) { (d: String) =>
      whenever (d.nonEmpty) {
        d.length shouldBe > 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are using ScalaTest?

Comment: Hi @ChrisStewart yes that was just an example, the DSL is not ScalaTest specific, the forAll side at least.

Comment: how does this work with an explicit generator given in the `Prop.forAll()` function?

Comment: @ChrisStewart Look at the method signature, I think there's an available overload for you that takes the generator as the first argument and the min passes as the next.

Comment: I don't see any way to do this with vanilla scalacheck sbt framework.

Answer (score 0):

It looks a little different for me using `munit`. Here is what worked for me,

```scala
import munit.ScalaCheckSuite
import munit.FunSuite

class FoobarTest extends FunSuite with ScalaCheckSuite {
  property(
    "Foo does the bar"
  ) {
    forAll { (intValue: Int) =>
      assert(intValue == intValue)
    }
  }.check(_.withMinSuccessfulTests(5000))
}
```